# DateFormatter Changes Date by 500 Years

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter, date-formatting

I am running the following code :

```
if let messagedate = curr_comment["timestamp"] as? String {
       let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
       dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
       let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(messagedate)
}
```

and here is the debugger output :

[image]

This started happening randomly today, I'm not sure why the date changes by 500 years through such a simple operation.

**EDIT:** This happens on a device that is using the Buddhist calendar.

Comment: It's undoubtedly because the `locale` for the device in question is not set for Gregorian calendar. If this `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS` format is for internal purposes (storing in database, communicating with web service, etc.), you should consider setting the `locale` of the formatter to `en_US_POSIX`. See [Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1480/_index.html).

Comment: Is this something I could do globally for the whole app in appDelegate or is it something I gotta do for every dateFormatter I use within the app

Comment: It's basically used to display how long ago a message/comment has been posted to other users of the app

Comment: Would I simply add this? `dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123653/discussion-between-rob-and-mankee).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the device in question is not set for Gregorian calendar. It is using the Buddhist calendar. See [Apple Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1480/_index.html) which discusses the proper handling of date strings to gracefully handle international calendars.

If this `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` format is for internal purposes (storing in database, communicating with web service, etc.), you should consider setting the locale of the formatter to `en_US_POSIX`. In Swift 3:

```
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```

in Swift 2:

```
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```

---

Frankly, this also begs the question as to what timezone the string representation of the date is using. You generally would want to make sure that date/time strings are consistently stored in UTC/GMT. In Swift 3:

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
```

Or, in Swift 2:

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)
```

If you do that consistently throughout the app, you'll avoid weird timezone issues (e.g. if someone in NY posts something right now, I don't want it to tell me in CA that it happened three hours ago).

Comment: how did you find out it's Buddhist?

Comment: I cheated. When I pointed out to the OP that the different calendars were the problem, he told me that the problem occurred on a friend's device using the Buddhist calendar. But this is a well known problem that occurs with a variety of non-Gregorian calendars, so it's less of a concern about the Buddhist calendar, specifically, than a general problem of failing to use a `locale` of `en_US_POSIX` .